# CV is sent but my phone number will be changed

Tags: resume, work-environment, phone

there is question bothering me: I am a Ukrainian citizen, will go to study to Luxembourg from September till February 2017. Meanwhile, I applied for the internship programme starting in Ferbuary, 2017. After the interview I have been shortlisted and my CV will be forwarded to the companies. I put my Ukrainian phone number in the CV but the thing is I will switch to Luxembourgish phone number in September and I will not be able to change it in CV. The number I specified in CV will be out of service of course.

I have about one week to inform the coordinator and send updated CV, how should I tell this issue in the CV? Write something like this phone number is not available from September, 14th, please write an email and I will send the new number? If yes, where should I put this, in the address box?

Comment: Is it possible to somehow include both phone numbers on the CV?

Comment: Have you considered forwarding the number, or if that is not possible set up a voicemail?

Comment: Not possible to include both numbers but thank you about the idea of forwarding the number, I will find out if this service is available at my carrier.

Comment: Well carrier said there is no way to fix this problem, will write to coordinator then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talk to the coordinator. Let them know the situation and they should know how to handle it. I would be surprised if this is the first time something like this has happened.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm going to assume your e-mail address won't change -- so that's always an alternative.

Do what Chris G said.  But if you're paranoid about missing the phone call, get something like a Google Voice number, and put that on the CV.  It will forward incoming calls to your new number.  Voila!

Comment: GV does not forward to international numbers, only US numbers: https://support.google.com/voice/answer/165221

Comment: There are other services, which is why I added "like" to the sentence.  Reading is fundamental.